# Can you match with regex and know which rule matched?

Tags: php, regex

So lets say I want to build a regex array that matches spam and if a match is found alert myself. It would be amazing if I could also see which regex statement caught it.

For example

```
$someArray = array (
    "Buy me",
    "only [0-9]*\ "
)
```

And it may return "Spam found: rule 1." (Index+1)

Comment: May be I didn't quite understand the task, but I think you can create an array of regex-es and run them in a loop. You can easly check if one of the regex items matches spam in a if condition (regex_match) and remember the index of an element of the array and thus identify the corresponding regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect which part of a regex mach you can put that part in a group and test later if it is empty or not. If it's empty that part did not participate in the match.

Or you can have a list of regexes that you apply one by one as you hint in your question. Then its just a matter of recording which individual regex matched?